# Making a button switch out an image on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There may be an easier way to do this, like with CSS, I think, pseudo-classes or whatever
but anyway for some reason I already wrote this function.

On `mouseup` it should switch the image back to normal. (Note that the images have the same names except for mouse down the `.png` is switched with `ed.png` and the opposite is done for document.mouseup. But document.mouseup isn't even working).

```
$.fn.buttonify = function () {
    console.log("buttonification successful");
    var that;
    var source;
    this.mousedown(function (event) {
        var top_value;
        var left_value;
        that = this;
        if (event.which == 1) { //if it is a left click
            source = this.src.substring(0, this.src.length - 4);
            source += "ed.png";
            this.src = source;
            console.log(this.src);
        }
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function () {
        if (that == null) {
            console.log("returninurnging");
            return;
        }
        console.log(source);
        source = source.substring(0, source.length - 6); //very questionable code
        source += ".png";
        that.src = source;
        console.log(that.src);
        that = null;
    });
}
```

When the mouse is lifted outside the click area, it does not change the image.
Otherwise it works. :(

Comment: ...What's the question?

Comment: ah! Just added it! when the mouse goes up outside of the image area it does not restore the image! D:

Comment: If the mouse is outside the click area then the mouseup event wouldn't fire on the element in question...ah but you are attaching the mouseup to the document...I wonder if the event propagates correctly?

Comment: AH! got it. just moved the document mouseup outside of the click, you are correct! I also added a prevent default to the event because it would screw things up on the drag ;D!

Comment: I was doing a jsbin for this. Should i post it?

Comment: Provide a demo: [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com)

Answer (score 1):

What do U really want?

```
<img src="image1.jpg" id="image">
<input type="button" value="whatever" onMouseDown="change()" onMouseUp="undochange()">
```

***JAVASCRIPT***

```
function change()
{
image = document.getElementById ("image");
image.src="image2.jpg";
}

function undochange()
{
image = document.getElementById ("image");
image.src="image1.jpg";
}
```